# How do I run a Flask Script from Spyder IDE?

Tags: python, flask, spyder

In Spyder, I wrote this code.
Why is it not showing on my browser localhost:5000?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the `debug=True` in your last call for things to work in Spyder.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `app.run()` use `app.run(debug = False)`, for the purpose of running.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your script? Your code SHOULD work. You have a couple of options:

Navigate to the folder your script is in within a terminal/cmd and enter the following:

```
python3 script.py
```

replacing `script.py` with the actual name of your script

Alternatively:

```
python3 script.py
```

If it successfully boots up the flask server it will give you the address and port its running on. By default it should be port 5000 like you have said.

But the address could be:

- http://127.0.0.1:5000
- localhost:5000

So try both, essentially the same but your computer might be weird.

I'm not familiar with the Spyder IDE, if it has a run button to start the script then press that and you should be able to access the server via either of the above addresses.

You could also try specifying a new port, maybe 5000 is being used?

```
app.run(port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the host and port like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```